# How do I get all images from a Cloudinary API without limit or how to use next_cursor?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, cloudinary

I'm developing a Flutter app and I have to show all images that I have in Cloudinary (300 images).
I was using this URL:

```
https://API_KEY:API_SECRET@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUD_NAME/resources/image/
```

But the problem is that it only returns 10 items and then the JSON response have an attribute called "next_cursor".

How can I get all URLs of each image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the API to [list resources](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_resources) you can use the `max_results` parameter to configure how many resources you get back in the response. As you've noted, this returns 10 by default but you can override that and set it to any number up to 500.

Next cursor, allows you to iterate through all the resources that matched the API call. You should check if the response to your first and subsequent API call has a `next_cursor` field in the response. This would be the case if there are more resources than the configured `max_results` that matched the query. If `next_cursor` is null/undefined then you've reached the end and there aren't any more resources to iterate through. Therefore, you should grab the value of the `next_cursor` from each API call and include it as a parameter in your subsequent requests. You can do this recursively or using a loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, I use this url and it works! :
`https://API_KEY:API_SECRET@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUD_NAME/resources/image/?max_results=500`